# passing a null password during execution of query in linux

Tags: mysql, sql

how to pass a password during the execution of a query in Linux if the password is null;`MySQL -u root -p`
this asks for entering the password every time the query is executed.

Comment: Well, then don't ask for a password. Leave the `-p` out.

Answer (score 0):

It's literally the first thing in manual

```
shell> mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```

or

```
mysql -uYOUR_USERNAME root -pYOUR_PASSWORD
```

> --user=user_name, -u user_name
>
> --password[=password], -p[password]
>              The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the
>   option and the password. **If you omit
>              the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, mysql prompts for one.**

Comment: my password is an empty string

Comment: `If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, mysql prompts for one.` just don't use `-p`

Comment: if i use like this `MySQL -uroot -p ` then it asks the password again

Comment: @ElavarasanThiru just use `mysql -uroot` or `mysql -uroot --password=""`